# Non-blocking on STDIN in PHP CLI

Tags: stdin, php

Is there anyway to read from `STDIN` with PHP that is non blocking:

I tried this:

```
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, false);
echo fread(STDIN, 1);
```

and this:

```
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
stream_set_blocking($stdin, false);
echo 'Press enter to force run command...' . PHP_EOL;
echo fread($stdin, 1);
```

but it still blocks until `fread` gets some data.

I noticed a few open bug reports about this (7 years old), so if it can't be done, does any one know any crude hacks that could accomplish this (on Windows and Linux)?

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34972
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47893
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48684

Comment: Not sure I understand what the non-blocking behaviour should be.  If there's nothing waiting to be fed to stdin, should `fread()` return a FALSE?  How would it differentiate that from EOF?  It seems to me you need some sort of test *other* than `fread()` to determine whether there's waiting data on stdin, since there isn't a descriptive failure.

Comment: @Graham `fread` will not return, i.e. pause the execution of the script, until input is given to `STDIN`. Basicly what I want, is to check if there is any user input to `STDIN`, and if not, continue, or else run some other stuff.

Comment: @Graham "Non blocking" means, that `fread()` should immediately return, even if it couldn't read the amount of data, that it should read (the second argument), but less then this. In this case it should return an empty string. @Petah did you try `fopen('php://stdin)`? I vaguely remember, that I had issues with `STDIN` earlier.

Comment: @KingCrunch, just tried that,  (as per my updated question), but had the same result.

Comment: So...  the behaviour that's supposed to happen with `stream_set_blocking(STDIN, false)` is that `fread()` never waits, and `if (strlen(fread($stdin,1)) == 0)`, then nothing is waiting to be input?

Comment: I just tried your second example (with fopen) on php 5.3.10 and the blocking behavior works as expected. This might be an environment-related issue.

Comment: @lzhang Which OS?, I can confirm it working on Debian, but not Windows. I need a cross platform solution.

Comment: @Petah I tested it on OS X. Sorry, I don't know much about streaming support on Windows.

Comment: The PHP version where it doesn't work, does it have readline support or not compiled in?

Comment: @hakre How would I tell? I am using 5.4.0 download directly from the PHP website. I have also tried 5.3.5 and 5.3.10 (from the XAMPP site)

Comment: Check the compiler flags, `phpinfo()` tells you. Standard windows distros don't have readline support.

Comment: @hakre Could not for "readline" anywhere in the PHP info

Comment: I'm not an expert but from what I know is, that it's not possible on windows to not wait for `ENTER` or sometimes `CTRL+Z` because the OS libs do not send the data to stream earlier. That needs some own libraries.

Comment: FYI. As of now, non blocking works PHP 5.6.24-0+deb8u1 (Linux). With readline but I think that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's what I could come up with.  It works fine in Linux, but on Windows, as soon as I hit a key, the input is buffered until enter is pressed.  I don't know a way to disable buffering on a stream.

```
<?php

function non_block_read($fd, &$data) {
    $read = array($fd);
    $write = array();
    $except = array();
    $result = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0);
    if($result === false) throw new Exception('stream_select failed');
    if($result === 0) return false;
    $data = stream_get_line($fd, 1);
    return true;
}

while(1) {
    $x = "";
    if(non_block_read(STDIN, $x)) {
        echo "Input: " . $x . "\n";
        // handle your input here
    } else {
        echo ".";
        // perform your processing here
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work for my case. But if you can get it consistent with (the enter key thing) then even better. Ill award you the bounty if there are no better answers.

Comment: I integrated this with my script, it works pretty well, except for the fact that it has to wait for enter. Every time I alt+tab to the Window, it pauses and waits for enter.

Comment: Just stubmle'd upon this question here and it might work if you're using stream_set_read_buffer(STDIN, 0); and, as you already mentioned, stream_set_blocking(STDIN, false); - The first one should set stdin to be unbuffered on reading, the second one set's it to be non blocking which is a bit different from unbuffered.

Comment: This is not working for me... It keeps me asking for an input to continue.

Comment: on windows it's not perfect, see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464457/why-stream-select-on-stdin-becomes-blocking-when-cmd-exe-loses-focus

Comment: This solution needs to be combined with user3684669's answer. Place the `system('stty cbreak');` to avoid buffering. I mean: This works looping on a "processing loop" while no key is pressed. Nevertheless you might need to press CTRL+D to indicate "end of buffer" to get the "Input:" message. Incorporating the `stty` trick from user3684669 the key processing does not need an "end of buffer signal".

Comment: By the way: Tested the "mix of solutions" in 2 weird scenarios: a) on a putty terminal sshing from a windows to a linux (php running in the linux, keyboard in the windows); and b) executing the script within in a docker (host windows, guest ubuntu) with docker `run -it` and prefixed with `winpty`like this: `winpty docker run -it ubuntu`. In both scenarios the "merge" of the two answers give a "parallel loop" to process while no input + immediate key response without waiting for enter or CTRL+D. Come on! Ideal for text-based gaming.

Comment: Even more... If you use `system('stty cbreak -echo');` instead of the normal `system('stty cbreak');` you don't get the echo of the pressed key.

Comment: How do you tell when stdin is finished (when piping to the script)?

Answer (score 5):

Just a notice, that non blocking STDIN working, now.

Comment: `stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 0);` does indeed work

Answer (score 2):

```
system('stty cbreak');
while(true){
    if($char = fread(STDIN, 1)) {
        echo chr(8) . mb_strtoupper($char);
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't know why this worked, but it absolutely worked for me! (ubuntu linux 18.04 gnu bash 4.4) thanks

Comment: This solution needs to be combined with Martin's solution. Otherwise, it won't have a "processing loop" while "waiting for a char". I mean: This works immediately, but only responds to a keypress. Martin's allows processing while no key is pressed. Good point for the stty trick.

Answer (score 1):

Petah, I can't help with the PHP side of this directly, but I can refer you to an article I ran across a while ago in which someone emulated transistors by testing within a shell script for the existence of pending data for a named pipe.  It's a fascinating read, and takes shell scripting to a whole new level of geekiness.  :-)

The article is here: http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/pipelogic/

So ... in answer to your "crude hacks" request, I suppose you could shunt your stdio through named pipes, then `exec()` the tool whose source is included at the URL above to test whether anything is waiting to be sent through the pipe.  You'd probably want to develop some wrapper functions to help with stuff.

I suspect the pipelogic solution is Linux-only, or at least would require a unix-like operating system.  No idea how this could be accomplished on Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really see how this helps with my problem.

Comment: @Petah - a non-blocking fread() that reads from a pipe could be duplicated by a function that would only run a blocking fread() after checking whether there's any data waiting on a pipe.  The tool at the link I posted lets you test that condition.  I'm pretty sure that this approach would not work in Windows because of the lack of named pipes, so I won't work it further, since Windows compatibility is a condition of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Martins Example above, and adding user3684669 code with a little modification of my own. Here is a small program displaying a clock and updating every second. When ever a key is pressed I echo it to the screen. I also hide the default echoing of the character to the screen. Works in Linux.

```
<?php
//-- Save the keyboard state
//-- then use cbreak and turn off echo
$stty_orig = '';
function init_keyboard() {
  global $stty_orig;

  $stty_orig = shell_exec("stty -g");
  system('stty cbreak -echo');
}

//-- Return keyboard state
function close_keyboard() {
  global $stty_orig;

  system('stty '.$stty_orig);
}

//-- clear the screen
function clear() {
  echo "\x1B[2J\x1B[0m";
}

//-- move cursor to x,y on the screen
function gotoxy($x, $y) {
  echo "\x1B[".$y.";".$x."H";
}

//-- print a string at x,y on the screen
function printxy($x, $y, $str) {
  gotoxy($x,$y);
  echo $str;
}

//-- Check if we have a character and return it if we do.
function non_block_read($fd) {
    $read = array($fd);
    $write = array();
    $except = array();
    $result = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0);
    if($result === false) throw new Exception('stream_select failed');
    if($result === 0) return false;
    $data = stream_get_line($fd, 1);
    return $data;
}

//-- main program starts here.
init_keyboard();
clear();
printxy(20,15,'Press Q to quit!');
while(1) {
    $x = "";
    if($x = non_block_read(STDIN)) {
        //echo "Input: " . $x . "\n";
        // handle your input here
        printxy(20,13,'Last Key Pressed: ['.$x."]  ");
        if ($x == 'Q') {
            printxy(1,20,"bye!\n");
            break;
        }
    } else {
        // perform your processing here
        $date_time = date('F j,Y h:i:sa');
        printxy(20,12,$date_time."   ");
    }
    sleep(1);
}
close_keyboard();
```

Answer (score 0):

When building CLI utilities with PHP I wanted my utility to both utilize arguments and/or pipes.
To solve this issue I've came up with this snippet that can be put at the top of your script.

```php
$stdin = null;
$is_stdin = fstat(STDIN)["size"] > 0;

if ($is_stdin) {
    while (true) {
        $c = fgetc(STDIN);

        // Why? Read this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php#67261
        if ($c === false)
            break;

        $stdin .= $c;
    }
}
```

This way you'll be able to check whether STDIN or Arguments were provided to the script.
*You can utilize both at the same time if you want.*