# Monitor size of php://stdin buffer

Tags: php, command-line-interface, stdin

I have a script reading from `STDIN`, the PHP CLI shortcut for `php://input`. Can I check to see how much data is left remaining in the stream?

I'm piping logs to a script, and I need a way to identify if the script is too slow and there is a backlog of incoming records.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows and PHP <= 5.4.1, you cannot. PHP only makes use of the blocking Windows API, which means you can either do a blocking read on STDIN or hope that the buffer isn't full, blocking the producer.

See [Non-blocking on STDIN in PHP CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356152/non-blocking-on-stdin-in-php-cli) for the list of PHP bugs filed against it.