# How can I check if stdin exists in PHP ( php-cgi )?

Tags: shell, stdin, php

#### Setup and Background

I am working on script that needs to run as `/usr/bin/php-cgi` instead `/usr/local/bin/php` and I'm having trouble checking for `stdin`

If I use `/usr/local/bin/php` as the interpreter I can do something like

```
if defined('STDIN'){ ... }
```

This doesn't seem to work with php-cgi - Looks to always be undefined. I checked the [man page for php-cgi](http://man.he.net/man1/php-cgi) but didn't find it very helpful. Also, if I understand it correctly, the `STDIN` constant is a file handle for `php://stdin`. I read somewhere that constant is not supposed to be available in `php-cgi`

#### Requirements

- The shebang needs to be `#!/usr/bin/php-cgi -q`
- The script will sometimes be passed arguments
- The script will sometimes receive input via `STDIN`

#### Current Script

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cgi -q
<?php

$stdin = '';
$fh = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

if($fh)
{

    while ($line = fgets( $fh )) {
            $stdin .= $line;
    }
    fclose($fh);

}

echo $stdin;
```

#### Problematic Behavior

This works OK:

```
$ echo hello | ./myscript.php 
hello
```

This just hangs:

```
./myscript.php
```

#### These things don't work for me:

- Checking `defined('STDIN')` // always returns false
- Looking to see if `CONTENT_LENGTH` is defined
- Checking variables and constants

I have added this to the script and run it both ways:

```
print_r(get_defined_constants());
print_r($GLOBALS);
print_r($_COOKIE);
print_r($_ENV);
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($_SERVER);
echo shell_exec('printenv');
```

I then diff'ed the output and it is the same.

I don't know any other way to check for / get `stdin` via `php-cgi` without locking up the script if it does not exist.

`/usr/bin/php-cgi -v` yields: `PHP 5.4.17 (cgi-fcgi)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create a endless loop with the `while($line = fgets($fh))` part in your code.

```
$stdin = '';
$fh = fopen('php://stdin','r');
if($fh) {
  // read *one* line from stdin upto "\r\n"
  $stdin = fgets($fh);
  fclose($fh);
}
echo $stdin;
```

The above would work if you're passing arguments like `echo foo=bar | ./myscript.php` and will read a single line when you call it like `./myscript.php`
If you like to read more lines and keep your original code you can send a quit signal `CTRL + D`

To get parameters passed like `./myscript.php foo=bar` you could check the contents of the `$argv` variable, in which the first argument always is the name of the executing script:

```
 ./myscript.php foo=bar

 // File: myscript.php
 $stdin = '';
 for($i = 1; $i < count($argv); i++) {
    $stdin .= $argv[$i];
 }
```

I'm not sure that this solves anything but perhaps it give you some ideas.

Comment: thanks but i don't think that this is the problem - I tried putting an echo statement in my while loop before posting the question and it did not continuously spit out output - I really do believe it is "hanging" trying to read stdin

Comment: Strange if I echo in the `while` loop I see different content each time I press enter? So if you write something and press enter and then do a `ctrl + d` you don't get the output echoed at all?

Comment: @cwd - If you call the script without any input i.e `./myscript.php` then it would stop at the `fgets(...)` until you press enter, isn't this the reason why you don't get any output if you add a echo inside your loop?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the select function such as:

```
$stdin = '';
$fh = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$read  = array($fh);
$write = NULL;
$except = NULL;
if ( stream_select( $read, $write, $except, 0 ) === 1 ) {
    while ($line = fgets( $fh )) {
            $stdin .= $line;
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: perfect solution! covers all my requirements

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your specific problem of hanging when there is no input: php stream reads are blocking operations by default.  You can change that behavior with [`stream_set_blocking()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php).  Like so:

```
$fh = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
stream_set_blocking($fh, false);
$stdin = fgets($fh);
echo "stdin: '$stdin'";  // immediately returns "stdin: ''"
```

Note that [this solution does not work with that magic file handle `STDIN`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356152/non-blocking-on-stdin-in-php-cli?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

`stream_get_meta_data` helped me :)

And as mentioned in the previous answer by [Seth Battin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004027/seth-battin) `stream_set_blocking($fh, false);` works very well

The next code reads data from the command line if provided and skips when it's not.

For example:
`echo "x" | php render.php`
and `php render.php`

In the first case, I provide some data from another stream (I really need to see the changed files from git, something like `git status | php render.php`.

Here is an example of my solution which works:

```
$input = [];

$fp = fopen('php://stdin', 'r+');
$info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

if (!$info['seekable'] && $fp) {
    while (false !== ($line = fgets($fp))) {
        $input[] = trim($line);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Note that this does not work with redirects. I.e. `$ ./foo.php< data-file.txt`