# Find position of console escape code in string

Tags: php

tl;dr How do I write `strpos($haystack, '^[[H^[[2J')` in PHP?

A linux command line app delivers a screen-full of data followed by a console escape code to return the cursor to the "home" position in a regular loop. To access the data I piped the output to my own script like so:

```
$ ./otherapp | php myscript.php
```

It's a continuous stream of data so I use [this example for non-blocking stream consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9711142/4623317).

Now to decode the output I need to grab a full frame/screen full of data. The escape codes are shown in nano as `^[[H` and `^[[2J`. The easiest way seems to be detecting these escape codes and using the output between them.

How are the escape codes represented in a PHP string? Can I use `strpos` (or mbstring equivalent) to detect their position?

Comment: `^[` is a terminal control sequence. it's not a literal `^` followed by a literal `[`, etc... it's one character whose visual representation are the two characters `^[`. it's the ascii char(27).

Comment: _"How are the escape codes represented in a PHP string?"_ - use something like `urlencode` as an easy way to get a look at the byte values contained in the data at such a position. Then use the \x or \u [syntax for double-quoted string literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) to create a string containing the euqivalent characters, and use that to search&replace or split at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're on a Unix environment. To achieve what your escape codes do, you can try with `echo -en "\033[H"` and `echo -en "\033[2J"`, so I guess you should try something like `strpos('\033[H\033[2J', $haystack)`.

Maybe you'll need to add an extra backslash (`'\\\033[H\\\033{2J'`).

Since `\033` means "the byte with octal value 33", which is ESC, this should work:

```
strpos("\e[H\e[2J", $haystack)
```

You need to enclose it in double-quotes (`"`) if you want PHP to interpret escape sequences for special characters.

Comment: Thanks! With double quotes `\e` works great, as does `\x1b` hinted by CBroe in the comments. I couldn't get octal notation to work but I didn't try too hard :)